# Particle escaping Tube

Tags: mesh, particles, import, faces

I have a tube through which I am trying to pass particles, however, the particles are escaping the constrain. I am using Blender 3.5. This mesh was created in Maya and has been imported as an FBX file. I have also checked it for a manifold object and mesh isn't broken. Please help.

I am using emit from faces option.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wtAEVpGMzqRP8m6WvQZxna0BgXIOkHo9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2):

Go to the *Particle Properties* and under *Physics* > *Integration* set the *Subframes* value to something higher than 0, e.g. 5 or 10. This will calculate the simulation more accurate and the particles stay inside.

[image: physics subframes]

By the way, sometimes the direction of the normals can also influence the interaction with the particles, like it would work better if they would collide with the outside than the inside of the mesh, but flipping the normals does not help in this case, you have to increase the subframes. Another way would be to decrease the *Timestep* values which you find above the *Subframes*, but this is less effective and slows down the movement of the particles.

Comment: Wow thank you for the help!!!

Answer (score 2):

apply scale + rotation for all objects which are part of the particle sim (collision + emission) and increase subframes to 5.

then i got:

[image]

Comment: Erster ohne Streit ;)

Comment: also erstens ist hier englisch die Mastersprache :D und zweitens hast du nachträglich editiert...also bist du eigentlich letzter :D gggggg

Comment: Stimmt, aber das Editieren war ja nicht mehr wirklich Teil der Lösung... nur zusätzliche Informationen die bei diesem Problem aber nicht helfen  :D  Oops, English please!

Comment: also billige Ausreden....zählen nicht...! :D editiert ist editiert. Was ist eigentlich mit Marty Fouts passiert? Wurde er Zeit seines Lebens gesperrt oder hatte er einfach keine Lust mehr? Der war doch auch täglich hier unterwegs....

Comment: Gute Frage... ich glaube ich habe schon ein Jahr oder so nichts mehr von dem gelesen. Vielleicht keine Lust mehr... oder benutzt kein Blender mehr?

Comment: kann ich mir ehrlich gesagt nicht vorstellen...dazu war er zu engagiert bei der Sache... ;)